# Growing Tree Algorithm in java not working seamless

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx

I'm trying to create a dungeon generator. First, I place the rooms randomly, then I grow a maze in the empty space between them. But I got a problem, everytime I run my maze algorithm, it creates sometimes strange unreachable corridors:

[image: Look at the red square]

[image: Same as above]

Take a look at the red squares there. These corridors are unreachable for the player. How to avoid them? Here's some code:

```
public void createMaze(byte[][] dungeon) {

    for (int y = 1; y < dungeon.length; y += 2) {

          for (int x = 1; x < dungeon[0].length; x += 2) {

              Vector2 pos = new Vector2(x, y);

              if (dungeon[y][x] != 2 && dungeon[y][x] != 1){
                  growMaze(pos, dungeon);
              }
          }
    }
}

public void growMaze(Vector2 pos, byte[][] dungeon) {

    // Initialize some Lists and Vars

    int lastDir = 0;

    ArrayList<Vector2> cells = new ArrayList<Vector2>();

    // Adding the startPosition to the cell list.

    cells.add(pos);

    // When the position is in the Grid

    if(pos.y < dungeon.length - 2 && pos.y > 0 + 2 && pos.x < dungeon[0].length - 2 && pos.x > 0 + 2){

        // And no walls or floors are around it

        if(isPlaceAble(dungeon , pos)){

            // Then place a corridor tile

            dungeon[(int) pos.y][(int) pos.x] = 4;
        }
    }

    // Here comes the algorithm.

    while(!cells.isEmpty()){    

        // choose the latest cell

        Vector2 choosedCell = cells.get(cells.size() - 1);

       // Check again if the cell is in the grid.


        if(choosedCell.y < dungeon.length - 2 && choosedCell.y > 0 + 2 && choosedCell.x < dungeon[0].length - 2 && choosedCell.x > 0 + 2){


            // When that's true, then check in which directions the cell is able to move


            boolean canGoNorth = dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y + 1)][(int) choosedCell.x] == 0 && dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y + 2)][(int) choosedCell.x] == 0;

            boolean canGoSouth = dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y - 1)][(int) choosedCell.x] == 0 && dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y - 2)][(int) choosedCell.x] == 0;


            boolean canGoEast = dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y)][(int) choosedCell.x + 1] == 0 && dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y)][(int) choosedCell.x + 2] == 0;

            boolean canGoWest = dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y)][(int) choosedCell.x - 1] == 0 && dungeon[(int) (choosedCell.y)][(int) choosedCell.x - 2] == 0;

            // When there's no available direction, then remove the cell and break the loop...

            if(!canGoNorth && !canGoSouth && !canGoEast && !canGoWest ){

                cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);

                break;
            }
            else{

                // But if there's a available direction, then remove the cell from the list.

                Vector2 savedCell = cells.get(cells.size() - 1);

                cells.remove(cells.get(cells.size() - 1));

                boolean placed = false;

                // And place a new one into a new direction. This will happen as long as one is placed.

                while(!placed){

                    // pick a random direction

                    int randomDirection = MathUtils.random(0,3);

                    int rdm = randomDirection;

                    // Init the length of the cells.

                    int length = 2;

                    // And now begin, if the direction and the random number fits, then dig the corridor. If no direction/number fits, then redo this until it works.

                    if(canGoNorth && rdm == 0 ){ 

                        int ycoord = 0;

                        for(int y = (int) choosedCell.y; y < choosedCell.y + length; y++){ 

                            dungeon[(int) y][(int) choosedCell.x] = 4;
                        }

                        Vector2 newCell = new Vector2(choosedCell.x, choosedCell.y + length);

                        cells.add(newCell);

                        lastDir = 0;

                        placed = true;
                    }

                    if(canGoSouth && rdm == 1 ){

                        int ycoord = 0;

                        for(int y = (int) choosedCell.y; y > choosedCell.y - length; y--){

                            dungeon[(int) y][(int) choosedCell.x] = 4;
                        }

                        Vector2 newCell = new Vector2(choosedCell.x, choosedCell.y - length); 

                        cells.add(newCell);

                        lastDir = 1;

                        placed = true;
                    }

                    if(canGoEast && rdm == 2 ){

                        int xcoord = 0;

                        for(int x = (int) choosedCell.x; x < choosedCell.x + length; x++){

                            dungeon[(int) choosedCell.y][x] = 4;
                        } 

                        Vector2 newCell = new Vector2(choosedCell.x + length, choosedCell.y );

                        cells.add(newCell);

                        lastDir = 2;

                        placed = true;
                    }

                    if(canGoWest && rdm == 3 ){

                        int xcoord = 0;

                        for(int x = (int) choosedCell.x; x > choosedCell.x - length; x--){

                            dungeon[(int) choosedCell.y][x] = 4;
                        } 

                        Vector2 newCell = new Vector2(choosedCell.x - length, choosedCell.y ); 

                        cells.add(newCell);

                        lastDir = 3;

                        placed = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{

            cells.remove(cells.size() - 1);
        }
    }   

    // And finally delete dead end cells :) (Those who only got 3 Wall/Floor neighbours or 4)

    killDeadEnds(dungeon);
}
```

So how to avoid these unreachable mazes?

Comment: Hint: you want **us** to spend our time to **debug** your code; so you want to make that as easy as possible. That starts with formatting/indenting **all** of your source code. You see, the more lines ... the harder for your brain to keep track of *context*. And you got dozens of **empty** lines in there that just make reading your code **harder** than necessary. Besides: have you at least tried to *debug* your code on your own?

Comment: Besides: look into creating a [mcve]. It is hard to figure what your code is doing ... when essential parts (such as the Vector2 class) are missing. Btw: Vector2 is a pretty nothing-telling name for a class.

Comment: Most algorythm are complex and very long. I cant make it even shorter. It is very well formated, i made comments and enough free spaces that you dont get confused, for a better structure. I tried it multiply times and tried dozens of other variants, but i simply dont get, why this is happening ever and every again. This post is also taged with LIBGDX, thats where the Vector2 Class comes from. Its bassicly a storage for one x and one y float. If you know how a Java vector works, than youll also know how a Vector2 ( Vector2D ) works.

Comment: And also i dont want YOU to spend time to DEBUG my code. I just asked for help, i dont force anyone here to take a look at my code. If there are any, who are interested in algorythm and are good in finding solutions, then those are welcome to help.

Comment: I am only telling you: you **over did** with vertical spacing. Yes, empty lines help to organize things for readability. But having an if, followed by two empty lines, followed by one statement, followed by another empty line is by **no means** "well formatted". Because the readers brain has to **sort** out all those empty lines that "contribute"; and those that do not. And for the record: my suggestion to improve your formatting shows +2 by now; your question is at -1. So, maybe; I am not alone with my remark there.

Comment: @genaray I agree completly with what Ghostcat said. You need to spend some time formatting this into a more readable format so it can be looked at with ease. In addition to that, if you need to debug the code then providing a working example of the code is important.

Comment: `killDeadEnds(dungeon)` I would like to see this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union-find structure to quickly find and remove all the cells that aren't connected to rooms.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

You initially create a disjoint set for each corridor or room cell, and then union every pair of sets for adjacent rooms or cells.  Finally, delete all the corridor cells that aren't in the same set as a room.

Union-find is also the basis for a nice maze generation algorithm, which is just Kruskal's algorithm for finding spanning trees in a graph ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm ) applied to a grid. See: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/3/maze-generation-kruskal-s-algorithm

You could use this algorithm to generate your maze in the first place, before applying your dead end removal.  It would change the character of your maze, though, so maybe you don't want to.